# Yii $criteria->compare to compare two tables to another table's values

Tags: php, sql-server, yii

[SOLVED]
I need to compare two ID tables to one Detail table in order to filter my CGridview.

The "Detail" table has has three important fields:

```
1 - id of the detail row
2 - ID of an assigned PERSON
3 - ID of an assigned GROUP (of PERSONs)
```

There can only be assigned EITHER a PERSON OR a GROUP. BOTH CANNOT be assigned. But at the same time NEITHER of them have to be in (either PERSON, GROUP or NONE)

then I have two ID tables for PERSON and GROUP.
basic with only an id linked to detail and a NAME defined as NAME.

in my CGridView I want to add both GROUP and PERSON in one field as SUPPORT because I know that they wont clash because of the EITHER rule earlier explained. so those values I've got in, as in such:

In columns array:

```
array(
    'header'=>'supp group/person',
    'value'=>'(!$data->assignedSupportperson && !$data->assignedSupportgroup ? 
        "null" : 
        ($data->assignedSupportperson ? 
            $data->assignedSupportperson->name : 
            $data->assignedSupportgroup->name
        )
    )',
),
```

easy enough but the difficult part is that I need to **add a filter to this column**.

so my logic tells me to use `$criteria->compare()` in my model to compare the two ID tables to the two columns in the DETAIL table. I have used `$criteria->compare()` to reference a ID table for text field filter, so I have some knowledge on that.

But if there's anyone out there who can manipulate a model well, please share your knowledge because I am lost.

[ADDED SOURCE CODE]
Grid View ::

```
$model = new TicketDetail('search');
    if (isset($_GET['TicketDetail'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_GET['TicketDetail'];
    }
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
        'id' => 'Assigned-Ticket-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->assignedToUser(Yii::app()->user->data()->id)->search(),
        'template' => "{items}{pager}",
        'htmlOptions'=>array(),
        'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed',
        'filter' => $model,
        'columns' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'id',
                'header' => 'ID',
                'headerHtmlOptions'=>array(
                    'width'=> 50,
                ),
            ),
            array(
                    'header'=>'supp group/person',
                    'value'=>'$data->AssignedSupport?$data->AssignedSupport:"null"',
                    //'filter'=>$model,    <----- heres where i tried a couple things.
                    'headerHtmlOptions'=>array(
                        'width'=>100
                    )
                ),
            ),
      );
```

model ::

```
public function getAssignedSupport()
    { 
    return !$this->assignedSupportperson&&!$this->assignedSupportgroup?"null":$this->assignedSupportperson?$this->assignedSupportperson->name:$this->assignedSupportgroup->name); 
    }
```

Is it not that you have to be able to search the value for the filter ? or am I under the wrong impression ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to add a calculated field to your `Detail` model:

```
public function getAssignedSupport()
{ 
  return !$this->assignedSupportperson && !$this->assignedSupportgroup?"null":($this->assignedSupportperson?$this->assignedSupportperson->name:$this->assignedSupportgroup->name;
}
```

Now, with Yii's `__get` function you can access the result of the above method as a property (e.g. `$data->assignedSupport`), like if it was an attribute from the database. It is a much easier and also cleaner way to add a calculated column to the model, than to the view.

**EDIT:**
To create custom filter and ordering for the calculated column in the gridview, you also have to edit the `search()` method in the model. Check out the following article for a practical example:
[Sort and filter a custom or composite CGridView column](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/590/sort-and-filter-a-custom-or-composite-cgridview-column-that-may-even-contain-data-from-different-tables/)

Comment: so instead of trying to filter via a the gridview i give it the illusion that there is a field with the name values in.. nice thinking.. that way it will filter via the illusionate field and work as though it come from the DB ... Thank You good sir .. ill try that out and let you know how it turns out .

Comment: I added the function and it worked perfectly to add the values i wanted. but still no filter box in the top . is there anything extra that needs to be added to filter in the gridview header or not ?? im quite new at all this so i really appreciate the help

Comment: There we go. I added the GridView to my original question under [ADDED SOURCE CODE] .. Thanx alot for your help. Im still a bit under the weather when it comes to fathoming Yii, But im on my way there :)

Comment: Now I see your problem. I edited my answer, see the referenced article for a practical example.

Comment: Thank You very much !! Exactly what is was looking for. I've gained alot of persective on how these things come together. I will put in all the added things in my question. Thanx again !!!

Comment: Got it all fixed and working perfectly. if you'd like to see the code id be happy to post them here ;) and THANKS AGAIN